# Is jBuilder faster than creating a hash and rendering it from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, jbuilder

I was developing a rather complex API and I have actually generated the desired hash from the service object.

Now, should I render the hash from the controller or create a jbuilder for this?

I don't like putting any logic inside jbuilders, so I prefer to create the hash inside my model/service.

Comment: I wouldn't beat myself up about using jBuilder for all JSON rendering. I find the whole idea of using views to create JSON objects incredibly backwards.   jBuilder is real slow compared to Active Model Serializers and the only reason it ships with rails is that it is DHH's pet project.

Comment: Also I haven't benchmarked it but I would guess that using jBuilder is slower by an order of magnitude than calling `{}.to_json`

Answer (score 2):

to_json is always faster. Much much faster. https://medium.com/@lgmspb/how-we-increased-the-speed-of-json-generation-by-3000-times-ca9395ab7337#.thpyf1wtc